# Document a recurring argument with a built-in type

Tags: scala, documentation, scaladoc

- Several packages have multiple classes with methods that have an argument called `p`.
- I want to document `p`.
- I can't document the type of `p` because the type is built-in (e.g. `Map[String, String]`).

How to document `p`?

```
class A {
    def (p: Map[String, String]): Unit = {}
}

class B {
    def (p: Map[String, String], ...): Unit = {}  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for type aliases:

```scala
/** Some doc for P type */
type MyPType = Map[String, String]

def someMethod(p: MyPType) = ...
```